# Can you cache more UITableViewCells than just those on display

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I understand that a UITableViewController will load only the UITableViewCells that it needs at the time, like a stack and as you scroll it UITableViewCells with be popped and pushed too and from the stack.

I would like to know if there is a way to define this stack yourself, for so instead of 12 or so UITableViewCells that are loaded initially for a full view UITableView could you make is 24 cells until the next one is loaded onto the stack?

Comment: That does sound a lot like an XY problem. Care to elaborate what you are actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: I would just like a few more objects loaded before the user might scroll to them... giving the user a better smoother experiance.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: so that the content inside the custom UITableViewCells I have create has time to load before the user progresses to them. I have an Image and a line of text that I am pulling from an online source.

Comment: You can pull the resources (image & text) before that and provide the loaded resources directly to the table cells. So no loading time anymore.

Comment: so is there no way at all to do what I want to do? I understand what your saying and i will do it that way. I would just like to know if there is away to make the UITableView stack larger than just the current cells in its view

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot configure the cell cache size of a UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Your app can preload and cache content for upcoming cells.  As the user scrolls through the table the UITableView can pull from this cache instead of having to wait to pull directly an online resource.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to pre-load more cells; why don't you fix the issue you're having and load the data in the background.

Do answer your question though; no, you cannot override this behaviour of UITableViewCell.